# How to use raw sql to extract values from a JOIN TABLE in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord

I've two tables users and places, joined by places_users.

I want to retrieve the last 5 places_users.

I'm trying:

Place.select("* from places_users")

but that's generating:

SELECT * from places_users FROM "places"

Do I need to use ActiveRecord directly? Or something else... 
Using instances of the models would not be appropriate, as that will give me just a users' places, or all the users that have selected a place.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: `PlaceUser.limit(5)` should do it.  Please reference: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#limit-and-offset

Comment: Hi, cheers for getting involved. However, I don't have a join table Model.

Comment: I would suggest adding the join model as you already have requirement for data data specific to that table.  Traversing it's columns via the other table might not be fun to code!

Answer (score 1):

you could try something like:

```
PlaceUser.includes(:place, :user).last(10)
```

which should give last 10 records from `PlaceUser` table with related `places` and `users`

if you don't have joined table you could create it:

```
class PlaceUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :place
end
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for getting involved.

The trouble is I don't have a join model. 

*wonders if I can just create a join model, and it'll work*

Comment: added `PlaceUser` model

Comment: Ok, I've got this working, but had to name the model, PlacesUser as it doesn't seem to auto-pluraralise Place! Clearly I'm now hacking it, but at least it works. 
Any obvious thing I should do to make it more 'Rails' like?

I should point out without the join model, the user place's are being added fine.